# Intersection of group $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the finite groups, $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ for prime $p$. What is the intersection of these two groups?

My naive guess is $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, so at least $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is in both of them.  Am I right?  How I can prove this in more rigorously?

Comment: The question, as written, is nonsense. You can’t intersect the two groups, because they are two separate groups. Unless you realize them as subgroups of a specific overgroup $G$ in a specific way, the question cannot even be asked. It’s like asking what is the intersection of an elephant and a giraffe.

Comment: Intersection in what?

Comment: The intersection of two disjoint groups is empty.

Comment: @ CyclotomicField, How I can show that?

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ are ordered pairs of the form $(x,y)$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}_p$. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ are *not* ordered pairs. The nature of the elements belonging to these sets are completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In retrospect this is an overkill answer, but anyway here it is.

Intersection is an extrinsic notion in the sense that for abstract sets $X$ and $Y$ it does not make sense to define $X\cap Y$ unless $X$ and $Y$ come equipped with injections $i_1:X\to Z$ and $i_2:Y\to Z$ where $Z$ is another set which we think of as containing $X$ and $Y$. Even so, $i_1(X)\cap i_2(Y)$ depends on the choice of embeddings.

In the case you are considering, the only reasonable way to pose the question would be to find a group $G$ into which $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ both have injective homomorphisms (equivalent  to existence of subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to these groups) and to then analyze the intersection.

However, this is still not well-posed because copies of these groups in $G$ can intersect with cardinality $1$ or $p$ depending on the group $G$. Indeed, $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\subseteq \Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ as $\{[np]:0\le n \le p-1\}$, and so in $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ there is a copy of $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ intersecting $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}\times \{0\}\cong \Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$ with cardinality $p$, while in $$\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}\times(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})$$
we have $(\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}\times \{0\})\cap (\{0\}\times (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}))=0.$